# Azure Function URL Does Not Return Output Over Some Networks

Tags: azure-functions

I’ve recently started testing Azure Functions and for the most part they have been working as expected. Something which I have noticed is over my work’s network the URL does not return an output and instead returns an ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED error message. What I have been trying to understand and research these last couple of days is not how to correct the error on my work’s network, but rather what can do to the Azure Function so that it works on any network regardless of the security. Researching this issue is difficult and I have not found a solution. I don’t even know if I am on the right track, but I tried creating an Azure virtual network NAT gateway, but this didn’t work or maybe I did something wrong.

Sorry for the long story, basically what I am asking does anyone know how to make an Azure function more reliable on any network? Any direction would be greatly appreciated. Many thanks!

Comment: Are you using a proxy at your work network?

Answer (score 0):

Its more of a network problem than an Azure Function problem really.

That being said, to get your Azure Function to work on protected networks you could set it up to [accept requests from a VNET using Private Endpoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-networking-options?tabs=azure-cli#private-endpoints) and then [setup a VPN Gateway to connect your local network to the VNET in Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/tutorial-site-to-site-portal?toc=%2Fazure%2Fvirtual-network%2Ftoc.json).

Ensure you have the right DNS entries and routing rules setup in your local network to route requests via the VPN Gateway to the Azure Function.